# Cookies Response Issue With AutoPostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I didn't know exactly how to put the title since i couldn't even describe the problem,, here's the problem..

(This is just the problem in brief)

Say I Have two CheckBoxes Set To AutoPostBack=True

```
protected void cbPop_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cookies["UserPreferences"].Value = Request.Cookies["UserPreferences"].Value + "1";
    Label1.Text = Request.Cookies["UserPreferences"].Value.Length.ToString();
}

protected void cbDown_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cookies["UserPreferences"].Value = Request.Cookies["UserPreferences"].Value + "2";
    Label1.Text = Request.Cookies["UserPreferences"].Value.Length.ToString();
}
```

**Here's What I expect :**

I expect the label's text to show "1" when i check the first checkBox and to show "2" when i check the second checkBox

**Here's What I get :**

I get "1" both times, when i manually check the cookie, i see it contains 12 so it's length should become 2 after checking the second checkBox, instead the label shows that it's length remains 1

WHY IS THAT !! Am i missing something ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the value right after CheckedChanged is called, you need to assign **Response** value to **Label**.

Otherwise, **Label** control won't reflect the changes until next time post back.

See the arrows in the comment area -

```
protected void cbPop_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cookies["UserPreferences"].Value = 
       Request.Cookies["UserPreferences"].Value + "1";
    Label1.Text = Response.Cookies["UserPreferences"].Value.Length.ToString();
    //                ^
    //                |
}

protected void cbDown_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cookies["UserPreferences"].Value = 
        Request.Cookies["UserPreferences"].Value + "2";
    Label1.Text = Response.Cookies["UserPreferences"].Value.Length.ToString();
    //                ^
    //                |
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read Response.Cookies["UserPreferences"].Value's lenth to label.
Not the Request's